# Setting layer properties for IBOutletCollection

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iboutlet, iboutletcollection

I'm trying to set the layer properties of multiple buttons connected to an `IBOutletCollectio`n but the `IBOutletCollection` doesn't let me access `UIButton.layer` the same as it does for a regular `IBOutlet`.

**Interface file:**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *customButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

**Implementation file**

```
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 9; // this works for individual buttons
customButton.layer.cornerRadius = 9; //This doesn't work for the collection of buttons
```

Am I missing something? Do I need to do something else to adjust the layer properties of a collection? I've imported QuartzCore into my implementation file.

I'm only trying to add 4 buttons to the collection so its not the end of the world if I have to set each on independently but it would be nice to be able to set them up together.

Comment: Note that customButton is NSArray type. NSArray has not layer property. May be you should change this property in loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

customButton is an NSArray.It doesnt have the layer as property.

Use this

```
for (UIButton *button in customButton) {
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 9;
    }
```